# ActiveMQ Artemis Management Console with HTTPS

Tags: activemq-artemis, hawtio

Is it possible to expose ActiveMQ Artemis (2.16.0) Management Console with HTTPS instead of plain HTTP?
Can't find any documentation on neither in Artemis docs or hawt.io to do that kind of setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/web-server.html) from the ActiveMQ Artemis User Manual.

You can simply set the `bind` attribute of the `web` element in `bootstrap.xml` to use `https` instead of `http`. Then, of course, you'll need to configure the other relevant settings like `keyStorePath`, `keyStorePassword`, etc.

Comment: Seems quite simple. Thanks.